# Python Dataframe to CSV - UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I use the following code to save roughly 6.000 scraped profiles from a dataframe to a csv:

`profiles.to_csv (r'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\profiles.csv', index = False, header=True, encoding="cp1252" )`

Inbetween the script stops giving me the following error message. The csv file contains roughly 1.500 profiles which were successfully written into the csv before it breaks - does anyone know how to solve this?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\alexa\PycharmProjects\cameo\main.py", line 75, in 
profiles.to_csv (r'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\cameo_profiles.csv', index = False, header=True, encoding="cp1252")
File "C:\Users\alexa\PycharmProjects\cameo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3466, in to_csv
return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
File "C:\Users\alexa\PycharmProjects\cameo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1105, in to_csv
csv_formatter.save()
File "C:\Users\alexa\PycharmProjects\cameo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 257, in save
self._save()
File "C:\Users\alexa\PycharmProjects\cameo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 262, in _save
self._save_body()
File "C:\Users\alexa\PycharmProjects\cameo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 300, in _save_body
self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
File "C:\Users\alexa\PycharmProjects\cameo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 311, in _save_chunk
libwriters.write_csv_rows(
File "pandas_libs\writers.pyx", line 72, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 15-22: character maps to

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

The error says that some cells in your dataframe contain character that cannot be converted into the cp1252 charset. If you have a recent version of Pandas (>= 1.0) you can use the `errors` parameter of `to_csv`. For example `errors='replace'` will just put a replacement character (often `?`) for any offending character:

```
profiles.to_csv (r'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\profiles.csv', index = False,
                 header=True, encoding="cp1252", errors='replace' )
```

Alternatively, you could try to use UTF-8 which can represent any unicode character:

```
profiles.to_csv (r'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\profiles.csv', index = False,
                 header=True, encoding="utf8" )
```

Comment: Perfect - now it works - Thanks!